# ZF2 Console routing gives an Request URI has not been set (missing route_match)?

Tags: php, routes, console, zend-framework2, url-routing

I am trying to build some Cronjobs handling.

I run my command (temp) from the CLI for testing:

```
php public/index.php send-private-messages-reminders direct
```

Therefor i created a Module with this routing in module.config.php

```
// cron route
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'cronjobs' => array(
                'type' => 'simple',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'send-private-messages-reminders <freq>',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\SendPrivateMessagesReminders',
                        'action' => 'task'
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Then i get my users and the messages for these users in my controller. I create my viewModel and prepare my mail:

```
$mailer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('\SxMail\Service\SxMail');
$sxMail = $mailer->prepare();
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

For the layout i want to use a layout that i use in my Application also. So i define my layout in module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'cron/mail/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/mail.twig',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

and set my layout:

```
$sxMail->setLayout('cron/mail/layout');
```

Also there is more code for instance for the template:

```
$viewModel->setTemplate('mailtemplates/private-messages-reminders.twig');
```

and setting variables for that template:

```
 $viewModel->setVariables(array( .... ));
```

So far so good. It works almost as expected. Only...

in my mail.twig template i use a ViewHelper for the urls, like this ie:

```
<img src="{{ url('mysite', {}, {force_canonical: true}) }}"images/merk-logo.png" />
```

In my Application everything is fine with the ViewHelper, but in my cron it is not. I get this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Request URI has not been set") in "application/mail/layout" at line ...
```

From here i'am at a loss. I can ask the routeMatch:

```
$routeMatch = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
```

this gives me:

```
object(Zend\Mvc\Router\Console\RouteMatch)#517 (3) {
  ["length":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["params":protected]=>
  array(3) {
     ["controller"]=>
    string(44) "Cron\Controller\SendPrivateMessagesReminders"
    ["action"]=>
    string(4) "task"
    ["freq"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  ["matchedRouteName":protected]=>
  string(8) "cronjobs"
}
```

but that is about it what i can find out. I have no clue what to do or how to solve the problem. I have been searching a lot, but the "solutions" so far are not detailed enough for me.

There is a missing route_match, but what to do about it?

Comment: You're getting _"Request URI has not been set"_ error because there are no HTTP Request exists when you run application from CLI and your matched route is an console route. Take a look : http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php I think best options are defining a global constant or config value in module.config.php

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean i can not use my ViewHelper for the urls? And do you mean that i use a global constant for the url instead?